# Rspec for conditional code if-else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, testing, rspec

I am new to RSpec but here I am trying to create tests based on this code and I am keep on getting this error. Any suggestions?
CODE:

```
  serialization_scope nil
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :destroy, :update]
  before_action :verify_user, only: :show


  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.build(list_params)

    if @list.save

      render json: {message: ['Success']}, status: 200
    else
      render json: {errors:[@list.errors.full_messages]}, status: 400
    end
  end
```

Here is the RSpec file that I started :

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe V1::ListsController, :type => :controller do

  describe "POST create" do
    it "returns HTTP status" do
      expect(post :create).to change(@list, :count).by(+1)
      expect(response).to have_http_status :success #200
    end
  end

  describe 'GET status if its not created' do
    it "return HTTP status - reports BAD REQUEST (HTTP status 400)" do
      expect(response.status).to eq 400
    end
  end
end
```

And the error that I got is :

```
Failures:

  1) V1::ListsController GET status if its created returns HTTP status
     Failure/Error: expect(post :create).to change(@list, :count).by(+1)
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block
     # ./spec/controllers/lists_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) GET status if its not created return HTTP status - reports BAD REQUEST (HTTP status 400)
     Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq 400

       expected: 400
            got: 200

       (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::ListsController, type: :request do
  describe 'valid request' do
    it 'returns HTTP status' do
      post '/list', params: { list: { list_name: 'xyz' } }
      expect(response.status).to eq 201
    end
  end
  describe 'invalid request' do
      it "should return unauthorized" do
        post '/list'
        assert_response :unauthorized
      end
    end
end
```

In params you need to pass your `list_params`.

Answer (score 1):

Spec would look like:

```
describe "POST create" do
  context 'valid request' do
    it 'should increase @list item' do
      expect { post :create }.to change(List, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "returns HTTP status" do
      post :create
      expect(response).to have_http_status :success #200
    end
  end

  context 'invalid request' do
    it "return HTTP status - reports BAD REQUEST (HTTP status 400)" do
      get :create
      expect(response.status).to eq 400
    end
  end
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hey rony thanks for your reply. But I am getting same error here
1) V1::ListsController POST create valid request increase @list item
     Failure/Error: Failure/Error: expect(post :create).to change(List, :count).by(1))
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block

Comment: change `expect { post :create }`
to  `get :create expect(response.status) `

Comment: exactly, you must have to `block` to match `change`.

Comment: This is more of a routing test than testing whether the object was created on not.

Answer (score 0):

You can test an object not being created by intentionally causing some of its validations to fail e.g. you can pass a mandatory attribute as `nil` from the RSpec.

Sample request: `post :create, { title: nil }`.

But as per your RSpec code, it seems there are no validations on `List` model. So, lets try to stub `save` and return `false` for this particular test.

```
describe 'GET status if its not created' do
  # Assuming your model name is `List`
  before { allow_any_instance_of(List).to receive(:save) { false } }
  it "return HTTP status - reports BAD REQUEST (HTTP status 400)" do
    post :create
    expect(response.status).to eq 400
  end
end
```

Please post your model for `list` and i can update the answer with more appropriate test.

Answer (score 0):

Ishika, let me see if I can help you :)

RSpec official documentation recommends you to use request specs instead of controller specs. That is recommended because Rails 5 deprecated some methods used on controller testings. You can read more about this [here at RSpec blog](http://rspec.info/blog/2016/07/rspec-3-5-has-been-released/)

ps.: You can use controller tests so far, but it can be deprecated in a future major version of RSpec.

There are some notes I left after the code, please read them also.

I would write a request spec like this:

```
# spec/requests/v1/lists_controller_create_spec.rb

require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe V1::ListsController do
  describe 'success' do
    it 'returns ok and creates a list', :aggregate_failures do # :aggregate_failures is available only for RSpec 3.3+
      expect do
        post '/list', title: 'foo' # This will also test your route, avoiding routing specs to be necessary
      end.to change { List.count }.from(0).to(1)

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end

  describe 'bad request' do
    before do
      # This is needed because your controller is not validating the object, but look at my
      # comment below (out of the code), to think about this behavior, please.
      allow_any_instance_of(List).to receive(:save).and_return(false) 
    end

    it 'returns a bad request and does not create a list' do
      expect do
        post '/list', title: 'foo' # This will also test your route, avoiding routing specs to be necessary
      end.not_to change { List.count }

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:bad_request)
    end
  end 
end
```

Notes:

1. I suggested using more than 1 expectation by example, that is ok in this spec because they are simple and because I'm using `:aggregate_failures` option. With this option, if the first expectation fails, the next expectations will also be executed, considering that in this case, the following expectations does not depend on the first one, it is ok to use more than 1 expectation for the example.[Reference](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures)
2. You are returning a bad request if the object is not saved, but you are not validating it. If your model has validations that will validate the object there, please adjust the specs to fail the save (instead of using the mock I used) and consider rendering an error message in the response
3. If you think that making the `post` inside a `expect` block, you can do different: Store the count of Lists in a variable before making the post and after the post you test if the variable has changed or not, maybe you think it will be more clear and it will do exactly the same thing in the background.